# Increase header size on Glassfish for Kerberos

Tags: glassfish, kerberos

Does anyone know how I can increase the max header size in Glassfish through the domain.xml? I don't have access to the Administration GUI and need to increase the header for Kerberos authentication.

Answer (score 0):

The http tag in the network-config/protocols/protocol section has two attributes (**header-buffer-length-bytes** and **send-buffer-size-bytes**) for this setting. Both parameters should be setup. In my example I use 65535 for this parameter:

```
  <network-config>
    <protocols>
      <protocol name="http-listener-1">
        <http request-timeout-seconds="300" redirect-port="443"
              default-virtual-server="server" max-connections="100"
              header-buffer-length-bytes="65535"
              send-buffer-size-bytes="65535">
          <file-cache></file-cache>
        </http>
        <ssl classname="com.sun.enterprise.security.ssl.GlassfishSSLImpl"
             cert-nickname=""></ssl>
      </protocol>
      <protocol security-enabled="true" name="http-listener-2">
        <http default-virtual-server="server" max-connections="250"
              header-buffer-length-bytes="65535"
              send-buffer-size-bytes="65535">
          <file-cache></file-cache>
        </http>
        <ssl key-store="keystore.jks"
             classname="com.sun.enterprise.security.ssl.GlassfishSSLImpl"
             cert-nickname="mynickname"></ssl>
      </protocol>
  ...
    </protocols>
  </network-config>
```